# How to denote dateSignedTabs to be EST

Tags: docusignapi

I have some dateSignedTabs but want the date to be EST so when I sign on July 17th at 00:22 AM EST, the date says 07/17/2023 and not 07/16/2023 as it is 21:22 PST. Is the date denoted by IP or something? I am just assuming it is PST.

```
                'dateSignedTabs': [
                    {
                        'anchorString': '//todays_date//',
                        'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
                        'anchorXOffest': '0',
                        'anchorYOffest': '0'
                    }
                 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to demo.docusign.net or [www.docusign.net](http://www.docusign.net)
2. Log into your DocuSign account.
3. From the top-right nav select **My Preferences**
4. From the left nav select **Regional Settings**
5. In the Date/Time Format drop-down select the one you want
   [image]